# AWS EC2 cannot connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

Guys
I had troubles with my EC2, I connected the EC2 through SSH successfully and used command line like “mysql -h ****.**.rds.amazonaws.com (myRDS Endpoint) -p 3306 -u **** -p****” to connect to the RDS, unfortunately, I got this error after a while: "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySql server on '****.**.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)'', there were several comments:

1. This EC2 and RDS are in same region and same available zone (Tokyo).
2. This EC2 is an classic one not VPC.
3. I can connect to to this Tokyo RDS through an EC2 located in other region (Singapore).
4. I get the same ERROR Info when using this Tokyo EC2 to connect to a RDS in Singapore and I'm sure Singapore RDS is available.
5. I tried "nc -zv  3306" using Tokyo EC2, but got a "time out" error while it succeed when using Signore EC2 to do this.
6. I checked the iptables of the Tokyo EC2, but there was no iptables there.
7. So, I doubt the problem is the EC2 not the RDS.
8. I google this and found the most similar questions are caused by SG, reason of this problem,

Very appreciated if any help, thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Beyond Wang

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the security group your EC2 instances are in is added to the security group for the RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your server IP to the RDS whitelist.